# ReadDataURL - Image not loading in firefox using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, image, webforms

I'm using this piece of code to load an image from my file system to user before he uploads it to server like following (enabling  cropping feature to the image):

```
  readURLFirstImage(document.getElementById("<%=FileUpload1.ClientID%>"));
```

Where the definition for the function is like following:

```
  function readURLFirstImage(input) {
      if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              $('#<%=before.ClientID%>').attr('src', e.target.result);
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
      }
  }
```

This works just fine using chrome browser. When I use it in firefox, the image isn't loaded at all...

How can I make this to work on all browsers?

Edit: This is the fiddle for the issue:

```
https://jsfiddle.net/novhd8k3/
```

For some reason it works here, yet there it doesnt... I'm confused right now..

@Vish here are the errors from console:

[image]

And here is the HTML of the fileupload control + image tag:

```
 <img style="width:100%;" id="before" src="" runat="server"/>
   <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"  /></div>
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle or plunker of it?

Comment: @Vish Okay hold on

Comment: @Vish I added a fiddle

Comment: Okay let me check, This works on both chrome and mozilla at my end, Will have to see in detail.

Comment: @Vish for some reason it works there just  fine on both browsers, but yet it doesn't works on mine :/

Comment: @JadinStojadin, do you have errors in console ?

Comment: @Vish could it be that I'm using built in asp.net fileupload control ... Hold on I'll show more HTML in my question

Comment: @Vish Okay ill check moment

Comment: @Vish No errors related to the controls or anything like that... Just some minor errors. P.S. I've updated my initial question with picture of the console

Comment: Let's continue here : http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132112/readdataurl-image-not-loading-in-firefox-using-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your `css`. File preview for `image` it is working properly.

Try this:

```
function readURLFirstImage(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = function (e) {
          $('#<%=before.ClientID%>').attr('src', e.target.result);
          $('#<%=before.ClientID%>').css('width','100px')
                                    .css('height','100px')
                                    .show()
                                    .css('visibility','visible');
      }
      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Another way is to set `css` directly:

```
<style>
      #before{
          display:block;
          visibility:visible;
          height:100px;
          width:100px;
      }
</style>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, you're the man! Although not sure why it set CSS correctly in chrome but not in firefox, but it works !:)